Hosted Shopify app on Heroku responding with server 500 error (SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused)
I have a Shopify app hosted on Heroku that is responding with a server 500 error (this error is not triggered by any specific line of code or human interaction).
I believe the issue is with MySQL is rejecting the Docker environment attempts to connect.

Illuminate\Database\QueryException and SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]
Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where
table_schema = ? and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE
TABLE')

The Heroku log tails shows other errors but I believe these are cascading issues from the failed connection.
However, I have not been able to figure out a work around.

I double checked my env file and all DB connections look correct

I added RUN apk add mysql-client to my dockerfile. No change

I also manually added the env file DB configuration into the Heroku config vars directly. So when you run Heroku config it responds with:
DB_CONNECTION: 
DB_DATABASE:
DB_HOST:  **not local host** acutal host is a mysql database in azure     
DB_PASSWORD:       
DB_PORT:        
DB_USERNAME:        
HOST:             
SCOPES:    
SHOPIFY_API_KEY:
SHOPIFY_API_SECRET:



Lastly, here is the full output from today when I run at the Heroku logs --tail:
scrubbed sensitive info
2024-08-21T04:10:59.839148+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2024-08-21T04:11:00.488050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2024-08-21T04:11:00.509315+00:00 app[web.1]: [21-Aug-2024 04:11:00] NOTICE: Terminating ...
2024-08-21T04:11:00.509328+00:00 app[web.1]: [21-Aug-2024 04:11:00] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
2024-08-21T04:11:00.628531+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2024-08-21T04:11:06.792929+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/app/entrypoint.sh`
2024-08-21T04:11:07.293306+00:00 app[web.1]: Running database migrations...
2024-08-21T04:11:08.087715+00:00 app[web.1]: Nothing to migrate.
2024-08-21T04:11:08.093413+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting nginx server...
2024-08-21T04:11:08.186291+00:00 app[web.1]: Service `hwdrivers` needs non-existent service `dev`
2024-08-21T04:11:08.186300+00:00 app[web.1]: Service `machine-id` needs non-existent service `dev`
2024-08-21T04:11:08.186506+00:00 app[web.1]: * Caching service dependencies ... [ ok ]
2024-08-21T04:11:08.202360+00:00 app[web.1]: * checkpath: owner `nginx:nginx` not found
2024-08-21T04:11:08.204663+00:00 app[web.1]: nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2024-08-21T04:11:08.209220+00:00 app[web.1]: * Starting nginx ...nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2024-08-21T04:11:08.211072+00:00 app[web.1]: [ ok ]
2024-08-21T04:11:08.214115+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting PHP server...
2024-08-21T04:11:08.238659+00:00 app[web.1]: [21-Aug-2024 04:11:08] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
2024-08-21T04:11:08.238736+00:00 app[web.1]: [21-Aug-2024 04:11:08] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 129
2024-08-21T04:11:08.239130+00:00 app[web.1]: [21-Aug-2024 04:11:08] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
2024-08-21T04:11:08.489892+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2024-08-21T17:09:22.087099+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 90b693b9 by user [email removed]
2024-08-21T17:09:22.087099+00:00 app[api]: Release v21 created by user [email removed]
2024-08-21T17:09:22.341631+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2024-08-21T17:09:22.394407+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2024-08-21T17:09:23.042588+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2024-08-21T17:09:23.060054+00:00 app[web.1]: [21-Aug-2024 17:09:23] NOTICE: Terminating ...
2024-08-21T17:09:23.060461+00:00 app[web.1]: [21-Aug-2024 17:09:23] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
2024-08-21T17:09:23.141668+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2024-08-21T17:09:28.641194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/app/entrypoint.sh`
2024-08-21T17:09:29.134483+00:00 app[web.1]: Running database migrations...
2024-08-21T17:09:29.867048+00:00 app[web.1]: Nothing to migrate.
2024-08-21T17:09:29.872716+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting nginx server...
2024-08-21T17:09:29.970252+00:00 app[web.1]: Service `hwdrivers` needs non-existent service `dev`
2024-08-21T17:09:29.970259+00:00 app[web.1]: Service `machine-id` needs non-existent service `dev`
2024-08-21T17:09:29.970417+00:00 app[web.1]: * Caching service dependencies ... [ ok ]
2024-08-21T17:09:29.984263+00:00 app[web.1]: * checkpath: owner `nginx:nginx` not found
2024-08-21T17:09:29.987109+00:00 app[web.1]: nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2024-08-21T17:09:29.992209+00:00 app[web.1]: * Starting nginx ...nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2024-08-21T17:09:29.994109+00:00 app[web.1]: [ ok ]
2024-08-21T17:09:29.997189+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting PHP server...
2024-08-21T17:09:30.019929+00:00 app[web.1]: [21-Aug-2024 17:09:30] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
2024-08-21T17:09:30.020002+00:00 app[web.1]: [21-Aug-2024 17:09:30] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 129
2024-08-21T17:09:30.020480+00:00 app[web.1]: [21-Aug-2024 17:09:30] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
2024-08-21T17:09:30.379115+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2024-08-21T17:09:55.071576+00:00 app[web.1]: 127.0.0.1 -  21/Aug/2024:17:09:54 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
2024-08-21T17:09:55.071965+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=[host removed] request_id=[id removed] fwd="[ip removed]" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=81ms status=500 bytes=7032 protocol=https
2024-08-21T17:09:56.155299+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=[host removed] request_id=[id removed] fwd="[ip removed]" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=0ms status=200 bytes=232 protocol=https
2024-08-21T17:09:56.773677+00:00 app[web.1]: 127.0.0.1 -  21/Aug/2024:17:09:56 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
2024


No, connection refused and authentication plugin cannot be loaded are two different, unrelated issues. In the first instance your app cannot even connect to mysql server.

@Shadow So if we focus on the connection refused + the output of the Heroku log tails. What would be causing that issue? Is it the way the docker container is trying to connect to the MySQL DB? I'm trying to wrap my head around what is really going on. Thanks!
